# Visual Studio 2005 does not break on unhandled exceptions, instead vshost crashes

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2005, break

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2005 Professional on Windows 7 32-bit.

For testing I am raising simple exceptions by using simple statements with divide by zero errors, or statements like Convert.ToInt32("asdf").

In all cases, I get "vshost.exe has stopped working..." with the option to attach a debugger.

In my Exceptions window, I have unchecked "Thrown" and I have checked "User-unhandled" for CLR exceptions.

If I check "Thrown" exceptions, then the VS debugger properly breaks on the DivideByZeroException etc.  But I have a lot of try/catch loops in my project and I want to only break on unhandled but it is refusing to work this way.

It was working fine on my old Windows XP machine with the same code.  It is working fine on my other team member's Windows XP computer (it breaks on the exception as expected).

Comment: Perhaps you need an update/service pack for Visual Studio 2005 so that it works properly on Windows 7. I would also consider upgrading to Visual Studio 2010.